How to add labels to all axis on a 3d plot?
I am trying to add labels to both axes on a 3d plot, in this case in the y-axis. But to make it more general, I would like to know how to add labels to all axes on a 3d plot. I have already looked through the manuals and other similar posts. It seems straight forwards to do it in 2D, but not so much in 3D.
Thanks.
My scrip looks like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% Preamble:
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.18,label style={font=\huge}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
    domain=-2:2,
]
 \addplot3 [
    samples y=10,
    samples=25,
    mesh,
    patch type=line,
    thick,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}



welcome! please modify your example so that we can compile it to reproduce the output you show. right now, nobody can work on this but you because only you have the .csv file required.

Thank you, I have changed the script into a generic one. I also added the numbers that I'd like to add in red, to exemplify.

much better - thanks!
